# Honeywell temperature attained but app says heating

Tags: heating, wifi

Recently set thermostat on iphone at 63, heat mode, but phone says 65 inside," heating".  Usually it would give me the temperature of the inside of the house and only tell me if it is cooling or heating if the HVAC was running. Not sure if the HVAC running since the desired temperature is attained but it says heating. We are out of town and use the app to monitor the HVAC

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: App says "heating" even though the temperature in the house is over the set temperature.  In the past if it stating heating or cooling the HVAC was running.  Has the app changed to indicate that the mode is on heat rather than the furnace actually running

Comment: you should be asking the app author

Comment: app author? In the past the cooling or heating was only apparent when HVAC was running.  Is this new?

Comment: yes, go to where you downloaded the app ... there should be a change log that you can read ... also there should be support contact info

Comment: I did not see anything in the app log but plan on calling honeywell in am.  Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is a question about a phone app, not home improvement.

Comment: I think it is more about the fact they just noticed the dead band on the thermostat.

Comment: A smart thermostat is a home improvement.  The question is about the behavior of the system, as observed through the app.  Owners of smart thermostats become more in tune with their HVAC systems through these apps and more motivated to learn about system behavior and potential for cost savings and improved comfort.   It is wrong to regard such questions as "about the app".  The app is the window onto the system that provides new motivation for homeowners to be more involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dead band set point in the thermostat
This set point may heat for several degrees above the set point and not turn on until several degrees below.
The dead band saves you $ because starting a furnace and heating / or cooling the duct work takes energy, so fewer starts and stops an hour end up saving $. where more on off cycles costing much more.

Many times they come +- 2 degrees so the furnace will not shut down until it is 2 degrees over the set point and it won’t restart until it is -2 or below the set point by 2 degrees.
That 4 degree swing is a larger than I like.
In the summer I do not let my system get above the set point so it is +0,-2 or -3. In the winter I don’t want it colder than the set point so I have it +2 or +3, -0 .

You can set it so it kicks on all the time by reducing the span the effect this has on your power bill is BIG. I wouldn’t go below 2 degree differential and 3 is better for energy efficiency. On the flip side a swing of 5 really starts to make no difference and people notice the cold or heat as not comfortable, with a span of 5 or larger swings.

So your thermostat is functioning the way I would expect.